# Magento set “Links can be purchased separately” to “No” for all downloadable products programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, product, admin, downloadable, script

I am using Magento CE 1.9.2.2 in my site.

How can I set `Links can be purchased separately` admin setting to `No` for all downloadable products programmatically.

I have tried following but it doesn't work:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once './app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                                                    ->addFieldToFilter('type_id', "downloadable");
foreach($productCollection as $product):
    $product->setData('links_purchased_separately', false);
    $product->save();
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Magmi](https://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) to achieve this. You have to put *sku, links_purchased_separately* in header row of import CSV. Then list all SKUs in first column and put 0 in *links_purchased_separately* column. Upload CSV via dataflow profiles and then run via Magmi.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it is not too late for an answer.
You should use `addAttributeToFilter()` instead of `addFieldToFilter()`.

In Magento `addAttributeToFilter` is using for **EAV module** (such as products), and `addFiledToFilter` is using for **flat tables**.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a product collection factory and a product repository in your constructor as follows

```
   \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
   \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository

$this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
$this->productRepository = $productRepository;
```

Then in your code use it as follows:

```
$productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create ();    
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect ( '*' );
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter ( 'type_id', 'downloadable');
```

The product collection will return a collection of products, so you'll need to get the actual products in the collection using the product repository. Try:

```
$ids = $productCollection->getAllIds();
    for each ($ids as $oneid)
{
    $product = $this->productRepository->getById($oneid);
    $product->setCustomAttribute('links_purchased_separately', false);
    $this->productRepository->save($product);
}
```

Instead of using 'setData', set a custom attribute on the product as above.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solution will definitely works for you

Steps to set **links_purchased_separately** to 0 for all downloadable product

- **Step 1:-** Go to **eav_attribute** table and search the **links_purchased_separately** and not down its **id** for me it is **125**
- **Step 2:-** Go to **catalog_product_entity_int** table and run this command **UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_int` SET `value`='0' WHERE
  `attribute_id` = '125'**